# Magento ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, custom, cache, user

Just for a specific customer every time when I tried to modify some Personal Information in the backend(customer section), or if I tried with the same user to access the cart or the checkout page, I receive this error in the browser: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

In `var/log` folder I don't have anything related to this issue.

What is really weird is the fact that only for one user this is happening, and unfortunately, i can't delete this user because there are many orders related with.

If i tried to do the same operations with other users everything goes fine.

What i found related to my issue is to  try flushing the APC Opcode cache by using:

```
 apc_clear_cache();
apc_clear_cache('user');
```

But when i tried to do this i receive "undefined method" error which means that i don't have PHP  APC extension enabled.

Does anyone know what i should do to solve this err?